# Prepositional phrase modifying a subject at the end of a sentence

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I want to express I was sitting on the couch watching TV. I heard that “I was watching TV on the couch” makes sense. I think a prepositional phrase at the end of a sentence can act as a subject complement, but I also want to know a prepositional phrase at the end of a sentence can act as an object complement at the end of any sentences (not only “treat” or “consider”).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. But I can tell you that PPs don't normally function as subject or object complements -- only AdjPs and NPs can do that. In your example, the clause "watching TV" is not a complement  but a depictive **adjunct**, giving descriptive information about the subject "I".

Comment: @BillJ, regarding that point, I am on the fence.

Comment: You should give us an example sentence of an apparent instance of a prepositional phrase serving as a subject complement and an apparent instance of a prepositional phrase serving as an object complement.